# how to access Year from Date written in cells, vba excel

Tags: vb.net, vba

I try this code, but an error message "Type Mismatch" is displayed.

```
If year(Sheets("Master-Deal").Cells(i, 9).Value) = 2012  Then

    result'''''''

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned from Excel is of type object. If the excel cell is a date you can try this:

```
If Year(CType(Sheets("Master-Deal").Cells(i, 9).Value, Date)) = 2012 Then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the value in target cell is not invalid date, you can check if it is a date using function `IsDate()`.

```
If IsDate(Sheets("Master-Deal").Cells(i, 9).Value) Then
    If Year(Sheets("Master-Deal").Cells(i, 9).Value) = 2012 Then
        ' do stuff
    End If
Else
    ' Complain about invalid date?
End If
```